# How to redirect https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com in IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

My site currently isn't working if I only type https://domain.com in the browser instead of www.domain.com,domain.com or https://www.domain.com.
My web config code is:

```
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.com/" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>


        <!-- code for redirect https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com/ -->

        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS without www" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
          </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.domain.com/" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>



        <!-- end -->


         <rule name="Add WWW prefix to DOMAIN.COM">
              <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain\.com" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution of this problem.

All rewrite rules were correct but in binding section on IIS we have added only three bindings, which were:

```
1.http://domain.com
2.http//www.domain.com
3.https://www.domain.com
```

And here binding was not added for https://domain.com, So once I added it all rules working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need:

```
 <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS without www" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.domain.com/" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```

Because this rule will do the same thing, redirect all `http` and `https` without the `www`.

```
<rule name="Add WWW prefix to DOMAIN.COM">
         <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain\.com" />
          </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
```

I think the problem you're having is that you're applying it at the `site level` and not the `server level` in IIS. So in IIS click on the machine name and then add the rules there, this will store it in the applicationhost.config file.

The Server level is circled in red, the site levels are below it.

[image]

Comment: So in IIS click on the machine name and then add the rules there, this will store it in the applicationhost.config file.Can you please explain more as I didn't get this is IIS ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking can you please clarify?

Comment: I am not able to get machine name on IIS, is it possible to give me any pictorial reference to perform this ?

Comment: udpdated answer